# Installing OpenCPU on Amazon Linux instance

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, opencpu

I have a an Amazon Linux instance which uses R to write a function to do some data analysis. I now want to call this function using a REST API. It seems that [OpenCPU](https://www.opencpu.org) can get the job done for me.

I have found links to install OpenCPU on Ubuntu, but is there an easy to way to install it on Amazon Linux instance.

PS: I tried

`sudo yum -y install opencpu`

`sudo yum -y install opencpu-server`

It says no such package available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it installed from this script https://github.com/jeroenooms/opencpu-server/blob/master/rpm/buildscript.sh.

Answer (score 0):

We now have rpm packages for CentOS 6 and 7 at https://archive.opencpu.org/